# Adobe experience cloud login

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

While I login to adobe analytics cloud, and when I go to products and select analytics than it is redirecting me to old lagacy login screen saying that:
'could not find an analytics account in company XYZ that is linked with this experience cloud account'.
Please suggest. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that would be best addressed by a system-level admin within your Analytics Cloud organization. It sounds like it is a permissions-based error.